# Dual boot issue on system with a SSD and an HDD

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, ssd, grub

I recently bought a new HP ProBook with:

- Intel i7 Processor,
- 8 GB RAM,
- 120 GB SSD,
- 1 TB HDD.
- Windows 10 Pro...

...pre-installed on the SSD which is `C:`, the system partition.
And there are two partitions created on the 1 TB HDD as `D:` and `E:` drives.

Now I wanted to install Ubuntu 18.04 on it as dual boot. For that I shrank `E:` and freed 250 GB and booted with Ubuntu bootable pendrive. After installing Ubuntu on the free space, at the end when installing Grub loader it showed an error.

I can't understand the problem. I tried twice, but same issue.

Is it due to the fact that system disk is a separate SSD disk where Windows is installed or something else?

How should I dual boot my laptop?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the error?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to answer your question. I would guess someone on youtube has ran into your problem and the answer is likely there.

https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=dual+boot+windows+10+and+ubuntu

Here is my answer: Dual booting is a thing of the past. My suggestion is that you look into setting a virtual operating system. VMware or VirtualBox. The wonderful thing about them you can be on both operating systems at the sametime. You don't need to partition your drive. The Virtual OS software will allocate more memory as you need it.

Alot of work goes into dual booting and removing a dual boot. Very little work goes into virtual operating systems.

The only downside I think there is, would be RAM. Depending on what you're going to be doing, I think 8 GBs is plenty. With a beefy enough computer, you could run games on the Virtual OS.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you'd better to put 2 boot partition in one disk.
Dual windows system require that,since bios Boot Priority only could choose one disk at the first.
Some configuration
https://itsfoss.com/guide-install-linux-mint-16-dual-boot-windows/